# Best constants c convention

Tags: c, enums, header-files

Suppose I would like to declare a set of constants in C (representing error codes of an application). how would you divide them into files ? would you use enum in external file and include it ?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2):

Yes, #defines or enums in a .h file is the way to go. Enums are useful if you're debugging with a debugger like gdb as you'll see a more descriptive value than a number.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a set of related numeric values, then an `enum` is the correct approach. If the values are C strings or otherwise not representable by an `enum` (or if they don't sensibly form a set of related values), you can use one of two approaches.

Either use preprocessor `#define` statements, or use `extern const`-marked variables. The former is resolved at compile-time, so you can use it to specify array lengths or to actively call code when used. The latter, however, allows you to change the value of the constant (by specifying it in a .c file rather than a .h file) without having to recompile every file that uses it.

Because `extern const`-marked variables can be changed in that fashion, they are preferable in code that is reused across many projects, or code that is distributed as a library. Changes to the library are then possible without forcing programs to be recompiled.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a set of values an enumeration declared in a header file would suffice (some people use #defines but since the value doesn't matter an enumeration works just fine in this case). If you simply want to compare to error codes this is a good method.